# How to take input of ManyToManyField of django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, manytomanyfield

I have 2 models - Rooms and Modules. A module can contain many rooms and a room can be contained by many different modules. below are the models -

Rooms model -

```
class Rooms(models.Model):
    room_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    level = models.CharField(max_length=100)
```

Module model -

```
class Module(models.Model):
    module_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    desc = models.TextField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    rooms = models.ManyToManyField(Rooms)
```

Module serializer -

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Module
        fields = "__all__"
```

Module view.py file -

```
class add_module(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
            module_serializer = ModuleSerializer(data=request.data)
            if module_serializer.is_valid():
                module_serializer.save()
                return Response(module_serializer.data['module_id'], status = status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            return Response("response":module_serializer.errors, status = status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

How do I take multiple rooms as input in views.py file while creating my module object. Also if i want to test my API in postman, then how can i take multiple inputs in postman.

Comment: You can use [writable nested serializers](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#writable-nested-serializers) in this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a similar construction:

```
class ModuleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   rooms = RoomSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)


   class Meta:
       model = Module
       fields = "__all__"


   def create(self, validated_data):
       rooms = validated_data.pop('rooms')
       ...
       for room in rooms:
           ...
       return Response(...)
```

Comment: Can you pls tell me how to use .add() method of ManyToMany field with module_serializer object. Because, according to documentation it can only be used with a model object.